# Bootstrap Tabs не меняются

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Есть сайт - [клик](http://demo.mydonate.su)

На нем есть табы, но при переключении по ним, контент не меняется.

Comment: Было бы очень удобно, если бы Вы предоставили [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас только 1 таб с формой, попробуйте добавить еще для других переключателей

```html
<div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="other">
  2й таб
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="case">
  3й таб
</div>
```